# Dynamiclly sized subplots added in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graph

I'm very new to graphing in `python` and I'm having trouble creating a subplot.

I currently have a loop that will produce 2 arrays which I then assign to Dataframe columns and use `df.plot()` to the graph. This results in me getting a different plot for every time through the loop.

I wanted to try and get everything on to one plot. I created the figure object outside of my loop and in the loop, I was trying the below code. I know I need to define the size of the subplot but the problem is the number of loops is user-defined. Also, regarding the shape - if it's 4 loops a 2x2 would be fine but if it's 25, id like it to try and approximate a square as best as possible. Not sure if that's doable.

```
        ax = plt.subplot(i)
        ax.scatter(y_df['y_pred'], y_df['y_test'])
```

but I kept getting the following error:

> "three-digit number, not {}".format(args[0]))
>
> ValueError: Integer subplot specification must be a three-digit
>   number, not 1

Here is my full code. I've removed a lot of the non-relevant lines to make it easier to follow:

```
  fig = plt.figure()


    tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=self.no_splits)
    for train_index, test_index in tqdm(tscv.split(X)):
        X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]



        self.regressor.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())

        # predict y values
        y_pred = self.regressor.predict(X_test)


        # plot y_pred vs y_test
        y_df = pd.DataFrame()
        y_pred = y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred), )
        y_test = y_test.reshape(len(y_test), )
        y_df['y_pred'] = y_pred
        y_df['y_test'] = y_test

        ax = plt.subplot(i)
        ax.scatter(y_df['y_pred'], y_df['y_test'])
```

Comment: That's because, when using subplot, you need to declare 3 numbers, for instance, if you want to plot 2 subplots vertically (above each other, the i in the ` plt.subplot(i)` would be (2,1,1) and the other subplot's would be (2,1,2) the first 2 declares that you have two rows, the 1 declares that you have one column and 1 and 2 declare in which row you want your subplot to be located.

Comment: Ah ok. So how do i do this if I dont know how many rows or columns i'll need? One time it could be 2x through the loop for 2 plots and another time can be 100. Is there a way to dynamically specify a figure size?

Comment: Well I don't understand how you can't know how many plots you need, I mean you are seemingly looping over all the `train_index, test_index` in `tqdm(tscv.split(X))`, hence if we assume you are doing the loop 20 times, you might want to have your plots to be 4 by 5, then I think you can do it by declaring an i in the loop which is increasing each time y_pred and y_test are getting new value, then do plot it by something like `plt.subplot(4,5,i)`

If you don't know how many plots you would have, set the number of rows and columns big to cover all plots, then just see how many are needed.

Comment: I guess what I was asking is what if the next time there's only 2 loops. I'd have to go in and change the subplot size to plt.subplot(2,0,i) or something like that? Thought there might have been a better way

Comment: You can set the size based on your looping, for instance, if you are looping n times, you might set the parameters in plt.subplot as (int(√n) +1, int(√n)+1, i)

Here I assume, n equals to  `len(tqdm(tscv.split(X)))`

Comment: getting close! now it looks like its freezing on the actual plot. I'm using ax.plot(y_df.index, y_df). Im trying to have datetime index by the x and have both columns plotted on the same index in each loop. It gets to the plot part and outputs blank screen.

Comment: it seems to work with the pandas plotting wrapper but not the matplotlib. No idea why. Is there anyway adjust the xaxis so I can see my dates better? they come up all jumbled together. Also - When I expand the subplot window, the X(Date and time) doesn't extend with each subplot

Comment: the help thus far is greatly appreciated by the way!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never used `TimeSeriesSplit` and that was why I didn't answer comprehensively, instead, giving some clues to fix the issue as far as I understand. other users would come and answer.

Answer (score 2):

add_subplot takes three arguments:

```
fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, index)
```

If you want to update the assigned location of the subplot(s) you could use "change_geometry" on the individual axes, which takes the same three arguments, e.g.:

```
for i,ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    if isinstance(ax,matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase):
        ax.change_geometry(len(fig.axes),1,i)
```

I've made a small example using "change_geometry":

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np
import random


def run(val):
    n_axes = int(val)
    ax_names = random.sample(range(max_size),n_axes)

    i=0
    for ax_name in range(1,max_size):
        # Delete outdated axes
        if ax_name not in ax_names and ax_name in my_axes.keys():
            fig.delaxes(my_axes[ax_name])
            del my_axes[ax_name]
        if ax_name in ax_names:
            i+=1
            #Plot new data on new axes
            if ax_name not in my_axes.keys():
                print(i,n_axes)
                y = np.random.rand(x.shape[0])
                my_axes[ax_name] = ax = fig.add_subplot(n_axes,1,i)
                ax.plot(x,y)
            # Relocate "old" ax to new position
            else:
                my_axes[ax_name].change_geometry(n_axes,1,i)



fig = plt.figure()
my_axes = {}
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
max_size=81

ax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.03, 0.8, 0.03], facecolor='#cccc00')
sNum = Slider(ax, '#plots', 1, max_size, valinit=1, valstep=1)
sNum.on_changed(run)
```